# ReadAsMultipartAsync returns error when no file provided

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I think my code was working previously with this same code

```
           var streamProvider = new CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(path);

            // Upload media               
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);
```

but now it gives System.InvalidOperationException error:
Access to the path 'C:\xxx\Projects\Test Projects\CL.MiClaim\CL.MiClaim\uploads' is denied.

When I provide a file for upload then it works al right. This below doesn't work (since it hasn't yet read the request content yet??)

```
 if (streamProvider.FileData.Count > 0)
            {
            }
```

any help will be appreciated.

Note: example code can be found at:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2

Comment: instead of looking at count look at the variable streamProvider and see what is different between when there is a file and when there isn't and check on that

Comment: Thanks Matt.. However I think its the same "Enumeration yielded no results" both times... and count being 0 (even with file)...

Comment: hmm,  maybe just put it in a try catch then with an empty catch where it uploads if there is a file and the error is ignored if there isn't

Comment: when no file is provided the MultipartFormDataStreamProvider still saves a file with 0 bytes! This is surprising (unless I am mistaken) as per the definition: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.multipartformdatastreamprovider(v=vs.118).aspx

**I am still looking to get an explanation for this.**

Anyways the error was because earlier I had a code that resulted in a null filename and hence the problem in saving a file without name.. and so it gave me the "access to path".. weird again.